# phalcon - loop through results and change values

Tags: php, iterator, phalcon

I want to loop through all the setting categories, and set variables depending on results.
So this way I can pass the updated array/object to the view and loop through it.
But I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference in  /app/controllers/SettingsController.php on line 9
```

My code:

```
<?php
class SettingsController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->tag->prependTitle("settings");
        $settingCategories = SettingCategory::find();
        $this->view->setVar("settingCategories",$settingCategories);
        foreach($settingCategories as &$settingCaterogy){
            if($settingCaterogy->type == "2"){
                $settingCategory->intersection = "deze mag niet";
            }else{
                $settingCategory->intersection = "deze mag";
            }
        }
        $this->view->disable();
        var_dump($settingCategories);
    }
}
```

And when I remove the &, the keys doesn't get defined or edited

Answer (score 1):

I assume your setting category is an object, meaning it's always passed as a reference. In which case you don't need to use & in your for each statement, nor you can't, as you've found out.

```
foreach($settingCategories as $settingCaterogy){
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the & from your loop iterator:

```
foreach($settingCategories as &$settingCaterogy){
```

to

```
foreach($settingCategories as $settingCaterogy){
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided by Bytchek and Teknotica are correct, and will get you around the error.  However, as far as I can tell the phalcon resultset object is read-only so the values you set won't stick.  A workaround is to convert the $settingCategories object to a regular array then loop through that (by reference:

```
$rw = $settingCategories->toArray();
foreach($rw as &$settingCategory){
    if($settingCaterogy["type"] == "2"){
        $settingCategory["intersection"] = "deze mag niet";
    } else {
        $settingCategory->["intersection"] = "deze mag";
    }
}
```